# Change Postfix email recipient on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I installed Postfix on my Ubuntu machine and i'm using Gmail's SMTP to actually deliver the emails using [this tutorial](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/).

This is the email headers:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; crmpicco-desktop
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 66487900105
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; crmpicco@crmpicco.co.uk
Arrival-Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 15:37:21 +0800 (AWST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; crmpiccocloud@localhost
Original-Recipient: rfc822;crmpiccocloud@localhost
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "crmpiccocloud"
```

Both the Sender and Recipient are wrong, however I can't see where these are configured. They don't appear to be referenced in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

How can I change the recipient (and ideally the sender too)? Is this configured alongside apache maybe?

Comment: You say "using this toturial".  _Which_ tutorial?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Apologies, my bad. Question updated. (https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/)